# How to efficiently shorten these if statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a project and in the code I added a few if statements. I was then told that I can do it on line and more efficiently. The way I did works perfectly but I need to refactor to get it accepted. Could you please help me out? I have tried ternary operator as you can see in the examples below but it's still not that short

Assuming that we have two arrays `arr1` and `arr2` and the following code is implemented to check if their lengths.

`const hasValArr1 = ():boolean => return arr1.length > 0` 
`const hasValArr2 = ():boolean => return arr2.length > 0`

Now the interesting part **if statements**

```
const isEmpty():boolean => {

if (!hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2()) return false

else if (hasValArr1() && hasValArr2()) return true 

else if (!hasValArr1() && hasValArr2()) return true 

else if (hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2()) return true

}
```

using ternary operator

```
 (!hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2()) ? false

:(hasValArr1() && hasValArr2()) ? true 

:(!hasValArr1() && hasValArr2()) ? true 

:(hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2()) && true
```

How would you go to write this in a more readable and efficient way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove ALL the `else if` statements and `return true` at the end. Even better, the entire function can be `return hasValArr1() || hasValArr2()`

Comment: do you really want to return for `isEmpty` `true` for some arrays with elements? it makes semantically no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation does not match the name of the method. The name of the method is `isEmpty` but it returns false if both arrays don't have a value: `if (!hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2()) return false`

So the name should be: `hasAnyValue` or `doArraysHaveAnyValue` or something of that sorts.

As for simplification, you can simply use `||`:

```
const doArraysHaveAnyValue(): boolean => {
    return hasValArr1() || hasValArr2();
}
```

The reason this is better is that it is easier to read, and gives preference to using "positive" instead of negation with `!`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can

```
сonst isEmpty():boolean => {

    if (!hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2()) 
       return false
    
       return true;
}
```

or:

```
const isEmpty():boolean => {
   return (!hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2())
}
```

or if you want to check whether the both arrays have values:

```
const HasArraysData():boolean => {
   return (hasValArr1() && hasValArr2())
}
```

and it becomes simpler to read code:

```
if (HasArraysData)
```

or:

```
if (!HasArraysData)
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the second one! Does it have use cases where it might not work as efficiently as the first one where you explicitly return false or true.

Comment: @davidio I think it should work like the first statement, it is just a bit little shorter

Answer (score 1):

Without questioning the premise of the question, you can write :

```
const isEmpty():boolean => {
   return hasValArr1() || hasValArr2()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to create separate function for check array length, you can directly use in **isEmpty()** function and get boolean value

```
const isEmpty():boolean => {
    return arr1.length > 0 || arr2.length > 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as you write, only the first case you want to return `false`, other
cases you want to return only `true`, that is why your codes will be like below

```
const isEmpty():boolean => {

if (!hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2()) 
   return false
else 
   return true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed with the approach you mentioned, *Then there are few suggestions or nice to have :*

- Instead of `return arr1.length > 0` you can simply use `return arr1.length`
- No need to use multiple conditions as you are checking if both the arrays contains value or not. Hence, you can simply modify your `isEmpty` function like this **:**

  ```
  const isEmpty() : boolean => {
    return (!hasValArr1() && !hasValArr2())
  }
  ```

My suggestion is instead of checking arr1 and arr2 length in the separate methods. You can check that in `isEmpty()` method itself.

```
const isEmpty() : boolean => {
    return !arr1.length && !arr2.length
}
```